# Strange results when using Scala collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have some tests with results that I can't quite explain.

The first test does a filter, map and reduce on a list containing 4 elements:

```
{
    val counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
    val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val filtered = l.filter{ i =>
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        true
    }
    val mapped = filtered.map{ i =>
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        i*2
    }
    val reduced = mapped.reduce{ (a, b) =>
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        a+b
    }
    println("counted " + counter.get + " and result is " + reduced)
    assert(20 == reduced)
    assert(11 == counter.get)
}
```

The counter is incremented 11 times as I expected: once for each element during filtering, once for each element during mapping and three times to add up the 4 elements.

Using wildcards the result changes:

```
{
    val counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
    val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val filtered = l.filter{
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        _ > 0
    }
    val mapped = filtered.map{
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        _*2
    }
    val reduced = mapped.reduce{ (a, b) =>
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        a+b
    }
    println("counted " + counter.get + " and result is " + reduced)
    assert(20 == reduced)
    assert(5 == counter.get)
}
```

I can't work out how to use wildcards in the reduce (code doesnt compile), but now, the counter is only incremented 5 times!!

So, question #1: Why do wildcards change the number of times the counter is called and how does that even work?

Then my second, related question.  My understanding of views was that they would lazily execute the functions passed to the monadic methods, but the following code doesn't show that.

```
{
    val counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
    val l = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4).view
    val filtered = l.filter{
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        _ > 0
    }
println("after filter: " + counter.get)
    val mapped = filtered.map{
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        _*2
    }
println("after map: " + counter.get)
    val reduced = mapped.reduce{ (a, b) =>
        counter.incrementAndGet()
        a+b
    }
println("after reduce: " + counter.get)
    println("counted " + counter.get + " and result is " + reduced)
    assert(20 == reduced)
    assert(5 == counter.get)
}
```

The output is:

```
after filter: 1
after map: 2
after reduce: 5
counted 5 and result is 20
```

Question #2: How come the functions are being executed immediately?

I'm using Scala 2.10

Comment: You really should accept Rex Kerr's answer (and not just give a laudatory comment)!

Comment: I will, but experience shows it's worth waiting for other answers, which might be better!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably thinking that

```
filter {
  println
  _ > 0
}
```

means

```
filter{ i =>
  println
  i > 0
}
```

but Scala has other ideas.  The reason is that

```
{ println; _ > 0 }
```

is a statement that first prints something, and then returns the `> 0` function.  So it interprets what you're doing as a funny way to specify the function, equivalent to:

```
val p = { println; (i: Int) => i > 0 }
filter(p)
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
println
val temp = (i: Int) => i > 0   // Temporary name, forget we did this!
val p = temp
filter(p)
```

which as you can imagine doesn't quite work out the way you want--you only print (or in your case do the increment) once at the beginning.  Both your problems stem from this.

Make sure if you're using underscores to mean "fill in the parameter" that you only have a single expression!  If you're using multiple statements, it's best to stick to explicitly named parameters.

Comment: Is there any way using views/streams to make Scala iterate over the elements just once, but to apply all the functions to the elements, to get the same result (20)?  Or do you have to write the code differently?

Comment: @JohnSmith - Filter, map, and reduce have sufficiently different semantics that no, you can't combine them in any easy way.  You can of course iterate once and do the filtering, mapping, and reducing by hand.

Comment: @JohnSmith: `.view` should filter and map the elements lazily. Thus calling `.reduce` should only iterate over the list once.

Comment: Someone else told me that, but testing didn't concur and if you look at the source, I'm not sure it ever will.  Sure, it's lazy, but it still seems to iterate for each monadic function.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Yeah, you're right--that's not how `view` works.  It won't evaluate until the result is needed, but if you need three different results it won't merge them into a single pass.

Comment: Someone else told me that typically the multiple iterations have no adverse effect on performance in comparison to the operations performed in the functions you pass to the monads.  Algorithmically it is the same whether you iterate once and say map and sum, or iterate twice, mapping once and then summing in the second iteration.  Think about the number of byte code operations it takes and the difference is small.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Well, that _might_ be true depending on the operations.  Generally traversing is comparably fast to the fastest generic operation (method call/field access), and very often you have an object creation per step, so traversal is no big deal.  But it's not _always_ true, and it can be particularly untrue with large collections where you pay hefty cache miss penalties twice (because it's not in cache any more by the second time you go through).  It wouldn't be at the top of my list of performance concerns, but if you're down to factors of 20% you may care.